# How to parse changes of the balances in json of a TX?

Tags: transactions, account, send-transaction, api

I sent `0.13 SOL` from one ordinary wallet to other. There's been no interraction with a smart contract, nor was it a token but SOL sent.

Here's a part of a TX in its raw form which I've obtained via API:

```
"preBalances" => [
    9997940920,
    0,
    1,
    1
], 

"preTokenBalances" => [],

"postBalances" => [
    9867934320,
    130000000,
    1,
    1
], 
"postTokenBalances" => [],
```

- Why are there 4 items in the `preBalances` and `postBalances` instead of 1?
- Although it's clear that one look at `130000000` as the new balance, why is this particular element? How to determine this?

What I need: given the address of a wallet, check whether it's been deposited any `SOL` or tokens on. In this particular case `SOL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you take a look at the transaction's json, you should also have an array of accounts. I think you have 4 accounts involved in your transaction (sender, receiver, and 2 solana core program account). The pre/post balance are displayed in the same order than accounts in the transaction (or instruction, i'm not sure, i have a doubt).

So you can check with the accounts array which wallet received sol / tokens.

You can also see that the first account was debited more than 0.13 sol, because there are transaction fees.

If you take a random transaction, there could be some difference in sol balance, it could also be linked to account creation. For example, if you send a token (nft, etc) to a wallet address that doesn't have the associated token account created yet, it has to be funded (0.002 sol or so).